# Unable to register JMX Metric Dropwizard

Tags: maven, jmx, dropwizard, metrics

I am trying to add JMX metric in my Dropwizard application, But when I am trying make it up locally it gives me error. I added following in my Application class in initalize method :

```
guiceBundle.addModule(new MetricsInstrumentationModule(bootstrap.getMetricRegistry()))
bootstrap.addBundle(new JmxMetricsBundle());
```

and in guice module file, I have added provider:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
MetricRegistry providesMetricRegistry(Environment environment) {
    return environment.metrics();
}
```

added below dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.palominolabs.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my class I am using it below way:

```
 private Timer getTimer(String name) {
    return metricRegistry
            .timer(MetricRegistry.name(DocumentService.class, name));
 }


 public void method(){
     final Timer.Context context = getTimer("methodMetric").time();
     try{
          //do something
     }finally {
        context.stop();
     }

 }
```

but when I am making my service up it is throwing following error:

```
DEBUG [2017-06-02 09:01:58,059] com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter: 
Unable to register timer! javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: 
metrics:name=io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.connect-requests


DEBUG [2017-06-02 09:01:58,066] com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter: 
Unable to register gauge! javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: 
metrics:name=io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.percent-
4xx-1m
```

And similar error messages, although my application is getting up successfully. I have no idea why this error is occurring, is it some localhost setup issue which will not happen on production or some genuine issue which I am missing. please help.

EDIT:
  JmxMetricsBundle class:

```
 public class JmxMetricsBundle implements Bundle {

 public void initialize(Bootstrap<?> bootstrap) {
    JmxReporter reporter = JmxReporter.forRegistry(bootstrap.getMetricRegistry()).build();
    reporter.start();
 }

 @Override
 public void run(Environment environment) {

 }
}
```